# How do I implement F using one 4-16 Decoder and a NOR gate?

Tags: decoder, logic-gates

I currently have more than 50% of question done I believe, but what I don't get is that why does the question ask me to use a NOR gate. Doesn't that change the value of F. For example, if I have 0000 my output F should be 0, but a nor gate would make it 1. I do recall my professor saying that 0000 actually gives 1 and we NOR it to get 0. How did he know it outputs 1?

[image: Work/notes]

*([Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08LGW.jpg))*

I am just confused why he said 0000 would give 1 on output. Or am I misinterpreting the question?

Comment: Were you told whether the NOR gate went on the input or the output of the decoder, or how many inputs the NOR gate has?  Or did you make an assumption?

Comment: i assumed to use at the end and my prof didbt say anything to me when i asked him this question and showed it.

Comment: One nor gate according to title which i the exact question copied out.

Comment: A NOR gate can have 2,3,4,...,n inputs, so "1 NOR gate" means you can use any number of inputs.  Look at your truth table, see any patterns in the outputs?  Maybe draw up a K-map and see if you can resolve the truth table into a logic statement?

Comment: i do notice patterns but now that I think about it why is it we only require m0 to m3

Answer (score 2):

Truth Table of 4X16 Decoder can be given as below
[image]

And F is the output of NOR gate whose inputs are M0,M1,M2,M3 (as per your figure)so for 0000 combination F value will be O and so on.

Comment: So i only connect the lines that are 1 to the nor gate o.o

Comment: Are you looking for "F" Output (Mentioned in your truth Table) from 4 to 16 Decoder?

Comment: Yes, but I am not sure how to connect it al together with one nor... I understand the truth table, but i am having a lot of trouble visualizing the endingnpic.

Comment: Isnt F alwaysvgoing to output one if we use a nor gate.

Comment: Nor will give output 1 only if all the inputs are 0.

Comment: Can you perhaps show me how it would look like?

Comment: Actually, should i be connecting aALL inputs into nor gate or just the ones that make 1?

Comment: I will suggest you to use two input Nor gate for one combination.For example in 1st combination 0000,Required output is 0.So connect M0 and any one from M1 to M15. For the combination 0001 required output is 1, so connect any decoder output to the input of NOR gate except M1.

Answer (score 1):

You either got it, or you were very close with your: "So i only connect the lines that are 1 to the nor gate o.o" comment. :-)

In any case, remembering that only one decoder output can be high at a time, you connect the lines which are high when you want "F" to be low, like this:

[image]